# variable scope in a getJson grep

Tags: jquery, scope, getjson

Im trying to use a variable within a grep of a getJson request. I want the variable to be defined based on a users' selection (the link they click on) -- but Im not sure how to pass it to the grep because it seems like the variable has to be defined within the getJson call?

This first example works:

```
$.getJSON('data/all.json', function(data)
  {
    location = $.grep(data, function(el, i)
     {
       var search=el.clicked_field;
       return search === "Y"
      });
     });
```

This 2nd one doesnt:

```
var search=el.clicked_field;
$.getJSON('data/all.json', function(data)
  {
    location = $.grep(data, function(el, i)
     {
       return search === "Y"
      });
     });
```

I think the issue was discussed here in the jQuery forum:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/variable-scoping-and-the-getjson-method

But I havent been able to replicate the proposed solution. Any help would be fantastic...

Answer (score 0):

you're defining `el` in the grep's callback in the 2nd one, which is why it's undefined outside that scope.

Comment: I'd also tried creating the variable like this --

var search= 'el.' + clicked_field;

but that didnt work either...?

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious difference in the two pieces of code is the movement of `var search=el.clicked_field` out of the context of `$.grep` to before the whole code body. At that point, `el` doesn't exist, yet. So, unless you have some other piece of code that covers that missing from your post, that's your problem.

**EDIT:**

Little JavaScript tip. Variables are global within their scope, so take for example the following:

```
$('#some-element').click(function() {
    var someElement = $(this);

    $.getJSON('url', function(data, jqXHR){
        console.log(someElement); // exists!
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** (again)

Okay, so you have some fundamental problems in your logic and syntax. It's becoming a bit tedious handling this one aspect at a time in comments, so I'm just going to illustrate:

```
$('#some-element').click(function() {
    var someElement = $(this).attr('href'); 

    // someElement == 'http://google.com'

    $.getJSON('data/all.json', function(data) {
       location = $.grep(data, function(el, i) {
           clicked = someElement.toLowerCase().slice(1);

           // clicked == 'ttp://google.com'   # Why?

           link = 'el' + '.' + clicked;

           // link == 'el.ttp://google.com'   # Why?

           console.log(link);  // This bit was for illustrative purposes, you should remove it from your code now.
           return link === "Y";

           // "el.ttp://google.com" != "Y"   # Obviously, and never will
       });
    });
```

`data` is a list of JavaScript objects. Passing it to `$.grep` will cause it to iterate through those objects. Each iteration, the current object will be stored in `el` and the index of that object within the `data` array will be stored in `i`. Take this bit of JSON as an example:

```
[ { "foo": 1, "bar": 2 } ]
```

If that was the returned JSON, then `el` would have attributes of both `foo` and `bar`, that you could then use to access the values of each, e.g.:

```
el.foo == 1 // True
el.bar == 2 // True
```

Maybe if you actually post your JSON response, I might be able to assist you further. (Update your question, *don't* post it as a comment)

Comment: Ok, yeah - I responded to another response that pointed that out too. I'd also tried constructing the variable outside of the getjson like this -- var search= 'el.' + clicked_field;
but that didnt work either.

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't. Why are you trying to do it outside in the first place?

Comment: So that the term that's used in the grep is defined dynamically based on what the user clicks on

Comment: Thanks... :} Do you know then how I'd access the el.someElement? I've tried nesting it within the example function but it doesnt seem to be taking the value -- $('#some-element').click(function() {
    var someElement = $(this);

    $.getJSON('url',
        function(data, jqXHR)
        {console.log(someElement)

        function(data)

        {
   location = $.grep(data, function(el, i)

         {
          return el.someElement === "Y"
         }); //rest of the function //

Comment: In that scenario, `someElement` is not an attribute off `el`. It stands on its own. The idea is that you save the element the user clicked on to a variable that then become global within that scope. Then, anything you do inside the scope has access to that variable, and hence the element the user clicked on.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Im not sure but it seems like this should be working -- 'someElement' is the global variable and 'link' is the variable with the right value within the getJson funtion. The console log displays the right value -- but the grep still doesnt return any of the objects...? 



$('#some-element').click(function()
 {
  var someElement = $(this).attr('href');
  $.getJSON('data/all.json', function(data)
  {location = $.grep(data, function(el, i)
    {clicked = someElement.toLowerCase().slice(1);link = 'el' + '.' + clicked;console.log(link);return link === "Y"});});